# Reusing calculated result in other mathematical expression for further calculation

Tags: angularjs

I am a noob in agular js so kinldy treat me like that

I am doing mathematical calculation in HTML using angularJS like below

```
<div>INR <span id="fv_formula">{{pv*(Math.pow((1+(rateofreturn.value/100)), tenure.value)) | number:2}}</span>
```

After getting the result in "fv_formula", I want to reuse the calculated result in many other calculation like below. As using "fv_formula" in every expression will make expression longer, complex and harder to debug

```
<span>{{ fv_formula / ((((annuityrate.value/100)/ 12 )*(Math.pow((1+((annuityrate.value/100)/ 12 )), lifeexpectancy.value*12)))</span>
```

As I have to use fv_formula in many other mathematical calculation with more complex formulas

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should be doing the math in your controller (or maybe a service) so the value is available throughout the app.

Comment: can you show me an example
It Will be great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What isherwood suggested is the following:

In your html add a controller

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <div>INR <span id="fv_formula">{{ result1 | number:2}}</div>
  <div>{{ result1 / result2}}</div>

</div>
```

Then you can create controller like

```
angular.module("your_app_name").controller("MainController",function($scope){

  //init your variables here

  $scope.result1 = pv*(Math.pow((1+(rateofreturn.value/100)), tenure.value));
  $scope.result2 = ((((annuityrate.value/100)/ 12 )*(Math.pow((1+((annuityrate.value/100)/ 12 )), lifeexpectancy.value*12)));

})
```

Eventually, you can also calculate in your controller whatever you want and just display it using handlebars

```
//something is defined within $scope, e.g. $scope.something = 5 will render 5 to html
{{ something }}
```

Comment: Thanks brother
if u can help in one other issue i will be very greatfull
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760478/cant-changes-default-value-after-inputting-new-values-in-output