# Can't changes default value after inputting new values in output

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to angularJS

Below is my controler

```
var app = angular.module('ChildPlanning', ['rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $modal)

 $scope.ir ={
   value:8
 };
 $scope.result1 = pv*(Math.pow((1+(rateofreturn.value/100)), tenure.value));
 $scope.result2 = ((((annuityrate.value/100)/ 12 )*(Math.pow((1+((annuityrate.value/100)/ 12 )), lifeexpectancy.value*12)));

 $scope.annuity_future = $scope.ir.value * $scope.result1  * $scope.result2;
}
```

My HTML

Input HTML 1

```
<input name="inflation" type="text" id="ir" ng-model="ir.value" >
```

Output html

```
 <span>{{ annuity_future }}</span>
```

When i am manually changing the default value of in input "ir.value" by typing in input field, the value in output is not changing accordingly

> Want to do this, thisway because i have to to do a long mathematical operation with lots of variable and with very variable i am using there i am facing the same issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because you never tell `ir.value` to take the value of `annuity_future`.

Comment: how should i do that ?

Comment: Is [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/UfbbZ3uXFcc9NRhEXHhz?p=preview) what you want?

Comment: have done edit in controller to show more precisely what i want

Comment: Thanks
Applying same method in rz-slider

Rz-slider example https://jsfiddle.net/ValentinH/954eve2L/

Using the first one, simple slider for getting value.
But again facing he same issue for getting the value in my final calculation from the slider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
$scope.change = function(){
  $scope.annuity_future = $scope.ir.value * $scope.result1  * $scope.result2;
};
```

And replace your input tag with this:

```
<input name="inflation" type="text" id="ir" ng-model="ir.value" ng-change="change()">
```

**Note:** make sure your calculations are valid, because I got an error that I missed one `)`.

Comment: thanks bro it  helps a lot
Just one more think i want to ask which i am not sure about i.e
$scope.annuity_future is accessible globally in controller or locally  within in the function

Comment: Every `$scope` is always globally accessible in the controller.

Comment: Thanks Applying same method in rz-slider Rz-slider example jsfiddle.net/ValentinH/954eve2L Using the first one, simple slider for getting value. But again facing he same issue for getting the value in my final calculation from the slider

Answer (score 0):

You can do calculation for `$scope.annuity_future` on ngChange or you can put the calculation directly in the html.

Output HTML

```
<span>{{ ir.value * result1  * result2}}</span>
```

Comment: Please see the edit I have done in controller to show more precisely what i want